# Hiding the page scroll control in a Reporting Services report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

If I force a report onto one page is it also possible to hide the following control?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Look at this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx)

You can hide the toolbar like this:

```
http://<Server Name>/reportserver?/Sales/YearlySalesSummary
&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Toolbar=false
```

The parameter you are looking for is that:

```
&rc:Toolbar=false
```

**Edit - Hide only the Page navigation using report viewer control (Win Forms)**

[First download the report viewer control](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442)

Then follow these steps:

- Add the report viewer control to the form
- Set the report server and report path URLs

Next customize the report properties in the `Form1_Load` method

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rpViewer.ShowPageNavigationControls = false;
            this.rpViewer.RefreshReport();
        }
```

The results should look like that:
[image]

Comment: +1 thanks for references; not read the article yet but will I be able to just get rid of those items from the toolbar or is it all-or-nothing ? i.e. either hide the _whole_ toolbar or have it all visible.

Comment: There is no way to hide only this with URL Parameters, but there is a way to do that using report viewer control in asp.net. if you can run the report using asp.net i will make an example for you

Comment: I have Visual Studio (mainly for `C#` `winforms`) but have never played with `asp.net` - how involved will this be?

Comment: Ho there is a way to do so in winforms, i will take the time to do a demo for youo

Comment: thanks - if we used `asp.net` would we be able to customize the actual report in the Reporting Services web server?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand the question

Comment: originally you mentioned using `asp.net` - do we have to use a form or am I able to customize the RS Web Portal i.e web site found at the TargetServerURL?

Comment: You most deffenetlly can customize it using asp.net. I will make you a simple example

Comment: thanks for going out of your way - did you create this extra example? - I think this might be the one I want as all our users access our reports via the out-of-the-box web site provided by `RS` so if I could customize reports displayed on that site then that would be first prize.