# How to show an RDLC report in C# Report Viewer with a vertical scroll bar?

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting, rdlc

I have generated a 9 page report using RDLC reports in C# VS 2010, but what I want is a vertical scroll bar so that I scroll down the pages like PDF instead of Page Next/ Previous button. I am searching and Googled it for answer but didn't find anything. I hope I am clear with my question. For any further detail please comment. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you force your report to a single page, I'm not sure if there's a way to do what you want.  See [Hiding the page scroll control in a Reporting Services report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065965/hiding-the-page-scroll-control-in-a-reporting-services-report) for something similar.  Is it a requirement that you view the report using the RDLC report viewer?  Something I have done before is use the report viewer to generate my report but I export it as a pdf and display it to the user using some other method/control.  For example, once the report is loaded you can call the code below.

```
byte[] bytes = reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

Depending on your application, use the memory stream or the byte array to display the pdf in a different control with a scrollbar.  That way you aren't limited by the report viewer page navigation buttons.

Comment: Thank you @Steve for your suggestion. But Its a minimum 9 page report hence cant force my report in one page. Rest thank you for your pdf suggestion but issue is I want to give "Export To PDF" as an option .

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are willing to only display report then you can change report page width.but to print your report either you would require specified page size or convert report to else format.you can set page size from here crystal report=>design=>page setup.

Comment: Anand I am not using Crystal Report.

Comment: ok try taking rdlc report viewer inside panel with vertical scroll=true;make sure panel width is greater than reportviewer.

Comment: Its about report viewer its showing only one page at a time. Without a vertical scroll to see other pages. Inside a panel the report viewer will behave the same. Rest I tried zoom feature but still not working much its zoom in and zoom out only on a single page of the report not on the complete report